# Google maps APIv2 markers not showing

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I have a odd problem with Google Maps APIv2 markers. I'm making a site where it shows both the map_canvas and the directions, but the marker image show on the directions but not on the map itself. Already tried updating API key, searched everywhere, but with no solution found at all.

The trouble is in this page: http://afonsogomes.com/jbutad2/contactos.php
By clicking "Obter Direcções" the map changes and the directions slide out.. you can see the map has missing marker images

However, this marker images DO show correctly on a test page I prepared here http://afonsogomes.com/jbutad2/comochegar.html

Any thoughts about this I'd be greatly appreciated

EDIT: All relevant code is inside the page and not in individual .js files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS. You are setting images to have a background colour, and transparent images react badly.

```
.image img, .image a img, .imageFrame img {
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
```

You need to remove that specification from the map div, perhaps with

```
#map_canvas img { background-color: transparent; }
```

Answer (score 0):

`google.maps.MarkerImage` is not available in V2 , your debugger should have told you about that.

Comment: It was working ok when I looked, and my solution fixed the problem. But there's quite a bit wrong now. I guess @AfonsoGomes is playing with the page.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: I didn't make the changes on my website ... just on my localhost! :)